# Getting image size from ByteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am wondering if there is any way to determine the width and height of an image that is decoded to a ByteArray.  For example in the below, any way to determine these values for data?

var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

data = encoded_image.decode(byteArrayData);

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded)
loader.loadBytes(byteArrayData);
```

-

```
function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var loader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(e.target.content).bitmapData;

    width = bitmapData.width;
    height = bitmapData.height;

    // cleanup
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
}
```

The downside is that the whole image is going to be decoded, so if you don't actually need the image, but only the width and height, you might actually want to look in the byte array and decode the file format. (More tricky, but

Comment: I am getting Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type.

Comment: I am getting an error when passing the ByteArray into the loader.

Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type.

Comment: probably the ByteArray you're providing is not good. Where is that byte array coming from?

Comment: Nice one! Works liek a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

you can read it from the header.
headers are different for each file type though.
look at custom image decoders, this is one of the things they do.

here is one for pngs:

http://ionsden.com/content/pngdecoder